# Writing to the appropriate log file in coffee script from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Instead of using console.log, I would like to have the coffee script generate an entry into the appropriate log file (production, development, etc.).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coffeescript will be compiled into javascript, then sent and run in the browser, therefore it won't have access to the logs in the server. 
For it to be possible, you'd need to create an API in the server where you'd send the messages to (using pixels, AJAX, or WebSockets for example) and write the logging logic there.

**Coffescript:**

```
log = (msg) ->
    $.post '/tracker', { data: msg }
```

**Routes.rb**

```
post '/tracker' => 'logger#create'
```

**loggers_controller.rb**

```
class LoggersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.debug params.data
    render :nothing
  end
end
```

Take this solution as a concept, it might not work right away if you just copy and paste. Also, be careful if you use such a solution in production, a malicious person can abuse it by sending data until your disk is full at which point your application may start to malfunction. (There are ways around it, of course)

Comment: So, it would be something like $.post('/route', "some text to write")? I don't know coffee, javascript or Ajax well enough

Comment: That's correct, I've edited the answer with an example for the coffeescript, but you are in the right track. You can use jQuery to post the data, then something like ``logger.debug params.data`` in the Rails controller (or however you prefer)

Comment: Do you think that I define the log error level to debug, this would work in production as well?

Comment: It depends on what log level you are setting for production. If you're using default values, I believe it will be ignored in production.